# Extract only most recent file based on filename

Tags: python, max, filenames

I want to unzip only the most recent file from files that have been updated. Here's my code:

```py
def main():

    dest_dir = 'C:/Users/PycharmProjects/kpi/flats'
    zip_file = 'Z:/OUT.zip'

    with ZipFile(zip_file) as zipObj:
        for zip_info in zipObj.infolist():
            if zip_info.filename[-1] == '/':
                continue
            if zip_info.filename.startswith('homeware/R2D2/DATA/OUT/Flat/FlatFile_r2d2_01012018'):
                print(zip_info.filename)
                zip_info.filename = os.path.basename(zip_info.filename)
                zipObj.extract(zip_info,dest_dir)
```

The extracted files are:

```
homeware/R2D2/DATA/OUT/Flat/Flat_01012018_180216.csv
homeware/R2D2/DATA/OUT/Flat/Flat_01012018_210147.csv
homeware/R2D2/DATA/OUT/Flat/Flat_01012018_230148.csv
```

But I want only the last one based on the filename and not metadata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I did is instead of extracting at each iteration, I appended the files that satisfy the 'if' requirements to a list. Then I extracted the max of that list which is the file I was looking for.
Here's the updated code:

```py
def main():

    dest_dir = 'C:/Users/mbelahce040119/PycharmProjects/kpi/flats'
    zip_file = 'Z:/DATA/OUT/COMMON_2018/201810/OUT_201810.zip'

    with ZipFile(zip_file) as zipObj:
        files_sat = list()
        for zip_info in zipObj.infolist():
            if zip_info.filename[-1] == '/':
                continue
            if zip_info.filename.startswith('homeware/R2D2/DATA/OUT/Flat/FlatFile_r2d2_01012018'):
                print(zip_info.filename)
                files_sat.append(zip_info.filename)
                zip_info.filename = os.path.basename(max(files))
        zipObj.extract(max(files_sat), dest_dir)
```